# Как работают сокеты в PHP?

Tags: php, websocket, сокет

Сколько с ними не работал, никогда не понимал их природу.

Если клиент отправил ДВА и больше последовательных сообщений, как сервер (пхп) их считает с помощью `fread`? За один такт все сразу или каждое сообщение по отдельности?

**Для чего надо:** создаю серверную часть Вебсокетов на пхп. Браузер отправляет несколько *последовательных* сообщений через `send()`, т.е. вот так:

```
websocket.send(сообщение1);
websocket.send(сообщение2);
websocket.send(сообщение3);
```

Без всяких таймаутов, событий и т.д.

Когда отправляет хром, на сервер приходит ТОЛЬКО первое. Когда отправляет лиса, приходят первые два. ВТФ??? Начал разбираться с серверной частью. И тут я столкнулся с тем, что совершенно не понимаю, как работают сокеты.

Comment: @kanaris, с сетевыми операциями вообще всегда есть непоределенность конца вывода. Если бы я сейчас брался за задачу, то я бы читал инпут в буфер до тех пор, пока там не наберется одно целое сообщение. После этого сообщение бы посылалось в очередь сообщений (откуда, скорее всего, тотчас же улетало бы в обработчик) и буфер снова набивался наличиствующими данными.

Comment: @Etki, т.е. вы имеете ввиду, было бы правильно так?
1) начать читать сообщение,
2) по первым байтам (в них может быть указана длина) определить длину фрэйма;
3) считать полное количество байт фрэйма;
4) если там остались какие-либо несчитаные байты, го то 1.

Наверное, скорее всего, так и буду делать. Видимо 3 сообщения пришли одним блоком, распознался только первый фрэйм, а остальные проигнорировались.

Comment: @kanaris в общем - да, только вместо "если остались несчитанные байты" "слушать дальше и скидывать все в буфер, очищая его при получении целого сообщения". Если хотите серьезно прокачаться в этой области, почитайте про устройство серверов, это прям-таки ежедневная сетевая задача.